# The document type declaration for root element type "hibernate-configuration" must end with '>' in eclipse

Tags: xml, hibernate, web-applications, configuration

the following is my hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">   

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
<property name="connection.username">bala</property>
<property name="connection.password">bala</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
<mapping resource="Products.hbm.xml" />
```

I  got the error when changed 'PUBLIC' to SYSTEM. and I am unable to run my web application if I turn off my internet connection

My question How to execute a Hibernate web program without the internet connection?

Comment: Can you please post the complete hibernat.cfg.xml ? The configuration posted does not has some closing tags.

Comment: unable to post full hibernate..cfg.xml .                                                 missed lines were                                                                                        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change a kind of Document Type Definition, you should know, that for the SYSTEM one only a system identifier must be given, though PUBLIC needs a formal public identifier and then a system identifier.

So, in your case, you need to make it like:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
    "classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

In this case, dtd file will not be downloaded, but used a local one, which must be on your classpath.

Comment: Okay, I understood.  But if I make the same change in Java project, there was no error.  Why? Could you explain me in more detail?

Comment: You mean, the error is only while you compile and run it via Eclipse? If so, I suppose, this is because Eclipse has it's own java compiler and it could sometimes behave differently

Comment: @Stanislav I had the same problem when I was teaching my students. I had the exact same code and it ran perfectly fine when I did it. Half of my students were able to do it as well. But couple of them had this parsing error. We tried a lot of things but couldn't get it to run